# Similar mathematic exercises about mathematical model

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, dynamical-systems, book-recommendation, mathematical-modeling

Where can I find similar mathematic exercises like the one below? 
(It does not need to be related to biology, it could be about anything)

I have a book that has some mathematic models about the Lotka-Volterra  equations and other kind of models **but** the book only  gives you the model with arbitrary parameters or just gives you the model with fixed constant, i.e. it doesn't gives you the **context**, like in the exercise below (about bees and trees).

The name of the book is Economic Dynamics
Phase Diagrams and Their Economic Application by Ronald Shone. Check page 607-608.

---

> Let $B$ be number of bees per acre, measured in hundreds of bees, while $C$ is the weight of trees per acre, in thousands of pounds. Suppose that the time is measured in months. $$\frac{dB}{dt}=.1(1-.01B+.005C)B$$ $$\frac{dC}{dt}=.03(1+.04B-.1C)C$$ 
>   Suppose one acre of land has 10,000 pounds of trees in it, and a beehive of 2,000 bees is introduced.
>
> What happens to the populations in future time?

Comment: @Moo The second book  doesn't have what I am asking for :)

Comment: @Moo Why did you delete your comment?, I haven't checked the first link :(

Comment: I delete all comments and answers that garner no votes. Here you go - problem set: http://www2.ups.edu/faculty/kirkpatrick/ecology/review%20problems/Unit%202/review2.htm, solutions: http://www2.ups.edu/faculty/kirkpatrick/ecology/review%20problems/Unit%202/review2key.htm